# Windows Genuine Advantage Won't Generate Code

Tags: windows-7, windows-genuine-advantage

I'm trying to download Windows Mobile Device Center 6.0 from Microsoft's website and they require I use Windows Genuine Advantage, I've done this lots of times before (including yesterday) and it has always worked.

Today though I get the following error and I'm really not sure what's going on:

[image]

I tried running MGADiag but that didn't fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple methods to simply fix 0x8004026a error code? Source: http://www.votedemos.com/0x8004026a.php

> There’s two types of strategies to take care of 0x8004026a Error code:
>
> **Advanced User Fix (manual):**
>
> 1) Switch on your laptop or desktop and then log on as an
>   administrator.
>
> 2) Then click the Get started button then click All Programs,
>   Accessories, System, and then click System Restore.
>
> 3) From the next window, select “Restore my machine to a previous
>   date” then click Next.
>
> 4) Select the most recent restore point from the “click a restore
>   point” list, and then click on Next.
>
> 5) Click the Next button in the confirmation window.
>
> 6) Restart the system whenever the rescue is finished.
>
> Beginner Resolution (totally automatic):
>
> 1) Download and open the (0x8004026a) fix tool.
>
> 2) Install program and then click Scan button.
>
> 3) Simply click the Fix Errors button once the diagnostic scan is
>   successfully done.
>
> 4) Restart the computer.

i hope it will help you about this more

***> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908440

> http://www.fixwindowserror.net/sitemap.xml***

---

These might help you:

- [You receive an error code and the copy of Microsoft Windows is not validated when you try to use Windows Genuine Advantage to validate your copy of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908440)

Comment: You may wish to either edit your other answer, or delete that, rather than posting multiple answers. You'd also want to cite, and provide appropriate links. In general copy pasting answers is considered undesirable on super user as well, and looking at things, your answer looks like that.

Comment: i try to correct myself from next post sir,thanks for valuable comments

Comment: don't copy paste answers, write/summarize them with proper links & attribution

Comment: +1 awessome answers. By the way vignesh you can add link on your second answer.